# Drupal webform saving password fields in plaintext

Tags: security, drupal

I have a test site which uses drupal webforms.

My register form has this following password fields. They are using the inbuilt "Password field" type

[image]

When I look in my MySQL db I can see the passwords in plaintext in the webform_submitted_data table.

What did I miss to allow this to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: I am not an expert in Drupal!**

With that being said, I'm guessing the password field is taking the data directly from the text field on the page and storing it in the table. This means that there's no validation or hashing taking place, and no security measures preventing you from any sort of attack.

Your best bet is to find a way to hash the data, along with some sort of unique and randomly-generated value as your salt. If you can do this, the password entered will be near unrecoverable. You'll also need to store the salt alongside the user's entry so that you can re-create the password later when the user re-enters it.

Another thing you could do is search through Drupal's forums or documentation and see if there's someone with the same issue, and whether or not they have a solution? It may also be in the official documentation that input sanitisation and validation, as well as hashing, are all done by the developer to meet their specifications - hopefully with instructions on how to achieve this.

Again, I've not a clue how drupal works - so the "fixing it" part is down to you. But I hope at least highlighting the problem will help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you for considering that storing passwords in plaintext in your database is not a good thing. It isn't. :)

I am believe this is Drupal 8 Webform? https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Answer:
I don't believe password fields encrypt any data submitted to them. This is just provides an HTML password field to the user.

Additional information:
I would carefully consider the need to save password in field data like this. It is hard to not miss something in implementation and create a security problem for you or your users. I definitely recommend having a Drupal developer who specializes in security to review and provide some alternative solutions based on your needs.

There does appear to be an option worth review (I mean this will need testing and security review for production usage). This module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_encrypt provides encryption for field data for the Drupal Webform module. It says it leverages the Encrypt module (https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt) which is a great module for encrypting data in Drupal if setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second what shrop said - why are you storing passwords in this form in the first place? I would re-examine the requirements for the form, going back to what the end goal is, and reconsider the entire architecture.